# How to manually set SKLearn Naive Bayes parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a trained Naive Bayes model and its parameters, but I need to deploy it on SKLearn. Is there any way to manually set the parameters for my model on SKLearn. AKA, how would I import an outside model into SKLearn to do prediction?

Thanks!

Comment: You could look at the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#gaussian-naive-bayes) for sklearn's implementations of Naive Bayes Models and then type in your parameters.

Comment: You could set coef_ by hand, I think. But you might need to set other parameters, too.

Comment: The [documentation for the implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) gives a list of methods without specifying which ones pertain to the coefficients in the model. Also, coefficients depend on internal counts which are saved, so there is probably a lot to change manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `pickle` module to serialize your transformers and estimators?

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html